# Sql query to find rows that only have one row (for exp license)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query pulling data from several tables, including one called `empl_access`. I only need the active employees who only have a `s_system_cd` type of `WEC`.

There are two values for this field: `WEC` and `WTC`. Employees could have both, but I want employees who only have the one, `WEC`.

Here is my script so far. This pulls all `WEC` rows but some of them also have the `WTC` and I want them filtered out.

```
select DISTINCT a.empl_id, a.last_name, a.first_name, a.active_fl,    
   b.UDT09_ABBRV_ID, c.s_system_cd, count(a.empl_id) over ()
from empl a, V_TBE_MAX_EMPL_HISTORY b, empl_access c 
where a.empl_id=b.empl_id 
   and a.empl_id=c.empl_id
   and a.active_fl='Y'
   and c.s_system_cd like 'WEC%'
order by a.empl_id;
```

This is a sample of what is in the table:

```
empl_id    | last_name      | first_name     | udt09_abbr_id       | s_system_cd
-----------|----------------|----------------|---------------------|-----------------
000000     | Mouse          | Mickey         | 1111                | WEC
-----------|----------------|----------------|---------------------|-----------------
000000     | Mouse          | Mickey         | 1111                | WTC
-----------|----------------|----------------|---------------------|-----------------
000010     | Duck           | Donald         | 1111                | WEC
-----------|----------------|----------------|---------------------|-----------------
000010     | Duck           | Donald         | 1111                | WTC
-----------|----------------|----------------|---------------------|-----------------
000020     | Parker         | John           | 1150                | WEC
-----------|----------------|----------------|---------------------|-----------------
000030     | Smith          | Anne           | 1152                | WEC
```

This is what I want to pull

```
-----------|----------------|----------------|---------------------|-----------------
empl_id    | last_name      | first_name     | udt09_abbr_id       | s_system_cd
-----------|----------------|----------------|---------------------|-----------------
000020     | Parker         | John           | 1150                | WEC
-----------|----------------|----------------|---------------------|-----------------
000030     | Smith          | Anne           | 1152                | WEC
-----------|----------------|----------------|---------------------|-----------------
```

Comment: Could you provide some samlpe data and expect result?

Comment: Stop using commas in the `FROM` clause.  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: You can join use a LEFT join for `empl_access` table _twice_, where each join looks at a specific `s_system_cd` value. Then the where clause can restrict records where the `WEC` option is not null and the `WTC` is null. Of course, this only works if you're using a join syntax that's not 20 years obsolete.

Comment: I can try that.  Are you talking about the join syntax I used?  I have not had formal sql training and I am being trained by someone who has been here 30 years.

Comment: Your desired results don't match your description, wouldn't Mickey and Donald be excluded from the desired results as they have both WEC and WTC?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: thanks Andrew you are correct.  I appreciate the positive feedback, we are all trained differently I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.empl_id, a.last_name, a.first_name, a.active_fl,    
   b.UDT09_ABBRV_ID, c.s_system_cd, count(a.empl_id) over ()
FROM empl a
INNER JOIN V_TBE_MAX_EMPL_HISTORY b ON a.empl_id=b.empl_id 
INNER JOIN empl_access c ON a.empl_id=c.empl_id AND c.s_system_cd like 'WEC%'
LEFT JOIN empl_access c2 ON a.empl_id=c2.empl_id AND c2.s_system_cd like 'WTC%'
WHERE a.active_fl='Y' AND c2.empl_id IS NULL
ORDER BY a.empl_id;
```

You could also do this with an `EXISTS` operation, or a `GROUP BY` and some fancy tricks with the aggregate functions (the min=max in the other answer works; so does checking the count = 1 and max = 'WEC').

The example in this answer is how you should **always**<sup>*</sup> write your joins.

The `empl a, V_TBE_MAX_EMPL_HISTORY b, empl_access c` stuff is for the birds. It gets harder to read and manage as you add more tables or conditions, there are certain things the old syntax just can't do, and the old syntax has been considered obsolete for roughly 20 years now.

---

<sup>* I don't use Oracle as often, but I understand there is a very rare situation that may require the  older syntax. But outside of this (and you'll know if when you find it), stick to writing out `INNER`, `LEFT`, `CROSS`, `FULL`, `LATERAL`, etc.</sup>

Comment: I so appreciate your information, it is helpful to hear this.  I have already decided to take some kind of database/sql class so maybe I can learn the new stuff.  I tried what you put above and substituted Exists as well and I am still getting the employees who also have WTC rows.

Comment: I had a copy/paste typo in the original version, was using `c` instead of the `c2` alias.

Comment: That is awesome Joel thank you so much!!! I am going to study this and learn the different joins.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this help?

```
SQL> with test (empl_id, s_system_cd) as
  2    (select 1, 'WEC' from dual union all  -- EMPL_ID = 1 has both - we don't want it
  3     select 1, 'WTC' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'WTC' from dual union all  -- EMPL_ID = 2 has only WTC - we don't want it
  5     select 3, 'WEC' from dual union all  -- EMPL_ID = 3 has only WEC - we do want it
  6     select 4, 'WEC' from dual union all  -- EMPL_ID = 4 has WEC, twice - we do want it
  7     select 4, 'WEC' from dual
  8    )
  9  select empl_id
 10  from test
 11  group by empl_id
 12  having min(s_system_cd) = max(s_system_cd)
 13     and min(s_system_cd) = 'WEC'
 14  order by empl_id;

   EMPL_ID
----------
         3
         4

SQL>
```